# Does uninstalling of an android app delete the database stored on sdcard?

Tags: android, sqlite, sd-card

I have a library app where I store each book as an SqliteDatabase. I save all the book dbs on sdcard. My question is if user uninstalls my app, then do all the dbs related to this app get deleted? If no, how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally **No** actually. When you uninstall, the APK itself (/data/app/com.example.app-1.apk) and the data (sharedprefs/db/etc) in /data/data/com.example.app is removed, but only Android >= 2.2 will also delete anything from the sdcard, and only a specific directory [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) (/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.app usually).

However some earlier versions of Froyo will also [delete when updating](https://review.source.android.com/#/c/16151/) an app, which makes it rather dangerous to use for persistent storage.

Comment: Ok, so how and where should I store these files to avoid such unpredictable behavior? If stored on internal storage then it soon gets filled up and it starts giving SqliteFullException. What is the best possible option to store such large number of files?

Comment: I use /sdcard/data/com.example.app . It's consistent in that it will never be deleted on uninstall or update. And it's not at the root level so users won't hate the mess it leaves behind. Instead of hardcoding "/sdcard", use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and append /data/ and your package name.

Comment: So, if I use /sdcard/data/com.example.app, then all the dbs will be deleted on uninstall, right? Also, can users access these files?

Comment: No, nothing stored there will be deleted at uninstall. There is no reliable way to have something from the sdcard removed at uninstall without risking it being removed at update on older versions of froyo. (And won't be removed at all on ecliar or older)

Comment: Yes, all the sdcard is public.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you put your files on some arbitrary place on external storage (SD card), they will not be deleted after you uninstalled your app. If you used `getExternalFilesDir()` (Android 2.2+) to get the directory to store your files in, they will be deleted when the app is uninstalled. On some early versions of Froyo, there is apparently a bug that deletes the files even on app upgrades, so you might want to watch out for this.

Answer (score 0):

answer is **Yes**.. everything is removed.. including `SharedPreference` and db.. You need not implement it by yourself.. for more red this..  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html